# Patchvalue only run once

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm just learning Angular and I've got a problem that I can't solve.
In my reactive form I have two ngb timepicker(startTime, endTime). I tried to subtract them then set another formcontrol(taskMins) with patchvalue. It works but only once and I would like to see that taskMins' value changes everytime when the timepickers' value changed.
This is from the component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  taskId: ['', Validators.required],
  comment: ['', Validators.required],
  startTime: ['', Validators.required],
  endTime: ['', Validators.required],
  taskMins: ({value: '', disabled: true}),
  isEditable: false,
  day: this.stringDate,
  });
  onChanges();
}

onChanges() {
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  if (this.myForm.controls['startTime'].valid &&
      this.myForm.controls['endTime'].valid)
      this.myForm.patchValue({taskMins: 
    (val.endTime.hour - val.startTime.hour) * 60 +
    (val.endTime.minute - val.startTime.minute)})
});
}
```

And from component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" formControlName="taskId" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" formControlName="comment" required>
      </td>
      <td> 
        <ngb-timepicker formControlName="startTime" 
         [spinners]="false" [size]="'small'" required>
        </ngb-timepicker>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ngb-timepicker formControlName="endTime" 
         [spinners]="false" [size]="'small'" required>
        </ngb-timepicker>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" formControlName="taskMins">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" 
                class="btn btn-success">
          Submit
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like valid code that should work, in my opinion. Are you sure there's nothing else impacting the form?

Answer (score 0):

First, is not correct to subscribe the forms value changes inside the onChanges() function. Every change detection cycle you are creating a new subscription and this will surely lead to a memory leak. You don't need to handle the onChange lifecycle because you are already listening to forms value changes.

Try just moving the code inside the onChanges function inside ngOnInit.

Comment: The onChanges method is called after initializing the form. It's `onChanges`, not the lifecycle method `ngOnChanges`

Comment: The problem is that you patch the value and trigger a new valueChanges each time. There are two possibilities: Either you subscribe to `this.myForm.get('startTime').valueChanges' and `this.myForm.get('endTime').valueChanges' and not the whole form, or you pass the`{emitEvent: false}` option to `patchValue()` so that the form's valueChanges is not retriggered.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the emitEvent version and it finally works.